# Remove UIViewController from UIView and release memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, deinit

I'm adding UIViewController in another UIView using:

```
self.addChild(vc)
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

and removing that UIViewController by:

```
for childVC in self.children {
   childVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
   childVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
   childVC.removeFromParent()
}
```

UIViewController remove from view but deinit of that UIViewController is not calling and it does not release memory of that UIViewController.

I'm not assigning any delegate to it that might cause strong reference cycle, what other thing I've to keep in mind to release it from memory too? Any other way?

Comment: Any closure that might be causing reference cycles? Or an object that holds a strong reference?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yes, one closure in UIViewController that was added in UIView, but I make it[weak self] too. It doesn't resolve issue.

Comment: See if You have any notification observers (in any of those two view controllers) that You are not removing appropriately?

Comment: @Whirlwind one of them has notification observers, observer removes code is in viewDidDisappear() method, and I checked it is called using breakpoint, but it didn't call in deinit only!

Comment: you said you add closures - it is also important what happens inside the closure that could cause retain cycles. I suggest to add more code of anything that you think could be causing issues such as passing closures, notifications or any other properties being assigned

Comment: Debug Memory Graph should answer your question (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use)–if something holds a strong reference to your view controller, you'll see what it is.

Comment: Why nor just adding the view and then releasing its VC ?

Comment: @PtitXav it has future navigation, so cannot add view only.

Comment: @lazarevzubov & Shawn I'll check other property as well and let you guys know how it goes

Comment: @DeepGandhi : where are the navigation ? In the VC ?

Comment: @PtitXav yes in VC

Comment: @Whirlwind I've doubt, don't we need to remove notification observers in deinit?

Comment: According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter) but I am still doing it :)

Comment: @DeepGandhi , i still not understand : you want to release the VC  but you  need it for future navigation ?

Comment: @PtitXav, when the view loads, I need that navigation, but when when remove the superview I think it should remove that UIViewController memory, navigation is needed while it was still there not removed (ie. goto previous page).